# Pass information from chrome extension popup.js to iframe so value is rendered on in field of page in iframe onload

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, cors, manifest

I have data that I have been able to pick from the page that the popup was called on.

I want to pass that data into the iframe which is showing the http://localhost:3000/. I want the values that were collected to show in the iframe fields when loaded. I have tried several things but haven't been able to get it to work.

manifest.js

```
    {
  "name": "Jb",
  "description": "RC",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Easy Jobs app",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.saltan.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["http://localhost:3000/*"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["insideIframe-content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log("from background.js", request);
});
```

insideIframe-content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ url: "link" });
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const appContainer = document.getElementById("app");
  let name;

  // Receive message from content script
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    if (message. Type === "Data") {
      const { Name } = message;

      updateUI(name);
    }
  });

  // Get the current active tab
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    const currentUrl = tabs[0].url;

    if (currentUrl.startsWith("https://www.saltan.com/")) {
      // If the current URL is on LinkedIn, proceed with loading the app
      const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
      iframe.src = "http://localhost:3000"; //my next.js app
      iframe.id = "iframe";
      iframe.style.width = "100%";
      iframe.style.height = "100%";

      // Add event listener for iframe load
      iframe.addEventListener("load", () => {
        // Access the iframe's window and post the message
        const iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
        console.log("Sending message to iframe:", {
          message: "getAppData",
          value: "MyDataToPass",
        });
        iframeWindow.postMessage(
          { message: "getAppData", value: "MyDataToPass" },
          "http://localhost:3000"
        );
      });
      appContainer.appendChild(iframe);
    } else {
      // If the current URL is not on LinkedIn, show a message to the user
      appContainer.innerHTML =
        "<h1>This extension is currently only available on saltan.</h1>";
      document.body.classList.add("not-on-saltan");
    }
  });
});
```

my actual next app has these functions within:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Add event listener for receiving messages from popup
    window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage);

    // Cleanup the event listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("message", handleMessage);
    };
  });

  // Method to handle messages received from the popup
  const handleMessage = (event) => {
    console.log("Message received in iframe:", event);
    const message = event.data.message;

    switch (message) {
      case "getAppData":
        // Process the data received from the popup
        const dataToProcess = event.data.value;
        console.log("Data received in iframe:", dataToProcess);
        // Call the function to update UI or perform other actions
        updateUIWithData(dataToProcess);
        break;

      // Add more cases if needed

      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  // Function to update UI with data received from the popup
  const updateUIWithData = (data) => {
    // Update the state variables with the received data
    setJob(data);
    // If you need to update more state variables, do the same here
  };
```

Not seeing any console logs associated with the page in the iframe

I have tried everything I can think of. Not sure if there is some cors's flag I have to flip in my app. Any help is deeply welcome

Comment: Assuming you inspect the iframe correctly through the popup's devtools, one reason might be that the listener is added after `load` event is fired on `iframe`. You can call parent.postMessage('ping', '*') from the nextjs app first, and the extension's window.onmessage listener sends the data.